# getting text aligned by css or a php function to add space

Tags: php, jquery, css, html

does anyone have a nice solution to get de price wich is a variable aligned vertically to the left side? no tables please!

the way it is now lines are displayed like this

```
input button $15.00 button
 input button $5.00 button
```

and it should look like this

```
input button $15.00 button
input button $5.00  button
```

I try'd php's sprintf or str_pad but it does not really do anything.

Any solution is helpfull.

My vision is getting blurry now from looking at the php pages

this is the html

```
<div class="item-checkout">
                <!--checkout item-->
                <form class="fcheckoutform" id="<?php echo $id_checkoutform;?>" method="post" action="">
                    <div class="naam"><?php echo $naam;?></div>
                    <div class="fr al">
                        <input name="qty" rel="<?php echo $rel;?>" type="text" size="3" class="aantal"
                        value="<?php echo $aantal;?>" maxlength="4" id="<?php echo $id_aantal;?>">
                        <span class="btn">Toepassen</span>
                        <span class="price"><?php echo $price_lbl;?></span> 
                        <span class="verwijder">Remove</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cbt"></div>     
                </form>
            </div>
```

thanks, Richard

Comment: Multiple whitespace characters are ignored for displaying by HTML.

Comment: Aligned with what? The input field?

Comment: how is it aligned now, and how do you want it to be?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you want and can you post the example with only the relevant code of what you have now on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: an accountant would say the first version is correct, not the second.

Comment: I get you, but the problem would be the same. The left side is shifting to the right when the price has les digits.One other way is to add space in the middle so the valuta sign is aligned to the left and the digits to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just play with the margin or padding?

```
input.naam{
padding-left: whatever_number_you_want px;
}
```

Comment: yes, maybe I will do it with inline style padding or margin using a  php variable to set the amount individually

Comment: If possible it's better to put your styles in the style sheet than inline. That way if you have more than one, you only have to change it in one place. Plus it's just a pain looking for a line of CSS in a mix of PHP/HTML.